# How to get all cookies of whole site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

like

```
my site : 

www.abc.com
www.abc.com/page1.php
www.abc.com/page2.php
www.abc.com/page3.php
www.abc.com/page4.php
www.abc.com/page5.php
....
```

I want cookies data of all the pages by executing single page. 
here I want to execute all pages in single page ie **getcookies.php** and wants to get the information of cookies in which page cookies are creating and how many cookies are creating and cookie names etc

```
www.abc.com/getcookies.php
```

Comment: Start with `document.cookie` or with jQuery's Cookie plugin, and see where it leads you.

Comment: That's not how cookies work. You don't fetch them: the browser sends them. And, since cookies are path based, you cannot for the browser to send a cookie for a non-matching path. What do you need to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

`$_COOKIE` is an array.

So, use following line:

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Also you can print it in **getcookies.php**

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE;
foreach($cookie as $key=>$value) {
    echo "$key = $value";   
}
```

Comment: but it will gives the current executed pages cookies .....how can I get the all cookies..by executing all the pages in single file

Comment: Cookie is domain specific, It should show all cookies (not page specific)

Comment: @Salim It really depends on the path with which the cookie was set. A cookie could have been set to `/`, which will make it available on all pages under the domain. But it also could have been set to a more specific path of the domain, which will make the cookie unavailable in other paths of the domain.

Comment: @Salim Yeah but ...if we execute the pages then only cookie will create and after if we execute  getcookies.php then it will show all created cookies. but I don't want to execute  the other pages.